# Star rating component - What are the correct accessibility and semantics to be used

Tags: html, svg, accessibility, semantic-markup, wai-aria

I have a star rating component that currently has the following semantic. The SVG are just stars.

```
<div role='img' aria-label="6 out of 6 ratings">
  <svg role="presentation"></svg>
  <svg role="presentation"></svg>
  <svg role="presentation"></svg>
  <svg role="presentation"></svg>
  <svg role="presentation"></svg>
  <svg role="presentation"></svg>
</div>
```

I have used the `role='img'` aria role as I want to ideal treat this image as one image. I have then used the `role='presentation'` aria role on the `SVG` as I think the SVG's alone provide no extra information so want to remove the semantic meaning to the SVG and it's children. I read about the [presentation role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_presentation_role) here.

I read a [article](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/12/using-aria-enhance-svg-accessibility/) on SVG accessibility and they go with slightly difference approach. The example they give is the following:

```
<body>
...
<svg xmlns=http://www.w3.org/2000/svg role="img" aria-labelledby="title  desc">
   <title id="title">Circle</title>
   <desc id="desc">Large red circle with a black border</desc>
   <circle role="presentation" cy="60" r="55" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" 
   fill="red" />
</svg>
…
</body>
```

- They use `role='img` on the svg. I believe this does not apply to my situation and would be better for me to keep `role='presentation'` on my SVG?
- They use `title` and `desc`. I believe that as a single star SVG it would not provide any extra benefit to the user? Also hovering over the SVG would reveal the title (and desc?) which I do not want.

Coming back to my example of how I currently have it:

1. Is there anything I can do to improve the accessibility/ semantic design to make it more user friendly?
2. Have I correctly used the right aria role for the container and the SVG?
3. Should I be able to tab through my rating image (as a whole) as for the aria-label to be read out?
4. Are there any other aria attributes I should be using?

Looking at the example on [semantic-ui](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/rating.html), they have no aria roles from what I can see.

Comment: Great question! I may be wrong about this but I imagine star rating as the equivalent of a group of radio buttons. I've done input-type-range-like svg and connected those svg with a real`<input type="hidden"` that takes it's value from the svg. I suppose you may do the same if you need to save the ratting in a data base.

Comment: Currently this is for just displaying the rating to a user. It already retrieves the correct percentage of stars to be coloured and not coloured, so I don’t need to store anything. So I’m not sure the above applies for my situation (might apply for others though depending on the rating functionality).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The MDN Web docs for `img` role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Role_Img) has a link to a [star rating role="img" example](https://codepen.io/svinkle/pen/oYjoNE)

They use `aria-hidden` instead of `role="presentation"`

According to the specs, the `img` role should already make its [children presentational](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#img)

I would add that being accessible implies more than just being accessible for screenreaders. For instance *"3 blacks stars, 2 white stars"* in the MDN example is something people may not understand (eg. people naturally reading from right-to-left).

> *"Grandma: Honey, Is it better to have 5 white stars, or 5 black stars?"*

I would say that adding "Note: 3/5" next to the ratings, might be a good help.

Comment: Oh man I'm blind as a bat and didn't see that example on MDN web Docs. Nice to know I wasn't too far off. Thank you very much